# Offline DB Support for POS

Tags: php, mysql, html, indexeddb, breeze

I been developing this Point of Sale system for almost a month and been stuck in finding a way to implement an offline support for my application. I want to use IndexedDB but having problems in what data should be loaded initially to the application.

Let me give you a scenario.

I started a transaction and entered some items. Unfortunately, the wrath of Thor destructed a tower which caused network disconnection while I am in the middle of transaction.

With that scenario, how should I structure my application?

A. Put all entries directly to the MySQL db and use IndexedDB for offline entries. (Problem: initial entries will never be brought back after disconnection.)

B. Use the HTML5 as the primary db for cashier transactions and transfer it only to the MySQL db after successful checkout. (Problem: a large amount of data will be stored to IndexedDB on system load.)

I am considering option B but can't find a way to minimize the size of preloaded data from the MySQL db. Why do I need to load these data? The only thing that identifies the item is throught the item code. I have thousands of items in the MySQL db and loading them into IndexedDB is overkill. I need to fetch the description, unit price, tax rate, discount rate, promo availability, and stock count of every item upon entry. Real time monitoring is also vital. If all of these data will be loaded to IndexedDB, 5mb is not enough.

Thank you so much for your responses!

Comment: IMHO, neither option is a runner. There will always be a risk of failure to detect stock-out, so you can't allow the user to go all the way through checkout. The best you could hope for is allowing items to be put into the basket or a wishList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start it is local storage that has a 5mb limit, the Indexeddb doesn't have a limit although browsers have the ability to limit it and of course your hard disk space is a limit too :).

Second: I would only use the indexeddb if you realy want the application to work fully offline. (For ex. Start the web app when you are offline and do changes on it.)

I think the what you want is just a fallback if the connection breaks, but a few minutes later you are able to sync after all. In this case I would keep the data in memory. This will ease the pain for you keeping your online and offline database in sync. Of course if you really want to provide an offline web application you will need the indexeddb API.

Take a look at upshot.js and [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com). This are libraries to keep track of your entities. Also these frameworks have some fallbacks (like keeping the data in memory) when you lose the connection for a short time.

To make things short whether to choose for indexeddb depends on the need that:

- Data needs to be offline available
- Changes must stay even if you close the web application and restart it after a while.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I also think TO question is not fit for client side database use. Transaction is apparent on server side. He could save shopping cart data though.